# Writing MySQL Records Using Entity Framework to Array

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, excel, entity-framework

I'm new to LINQ and Entity Framework for that matter. I'm using data from MySQL to write to an Excel worksheet.  Basic arrays are the fastest way to bulk write to worksheets.  So my question is, what would the fastest way be to populate an array?  Using LINQ?  My tables in MySQL are made up of composite keys so I would select records based on a few criteria.

I got to the point where I **size the array**:

```
var rows = (from o in context.HoldingsEntitySet
            where o.AccountNumber == accountNumber 
            select o).Count();
```

Then I **create the array**:

```
var holdingsArray = new object[rows, 4];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I'm a little stumped on how to do this!

thanks,
Justin

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of the data you're trying to turn into the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var rows = (from o in context.HoldingsEntitySet
            where o.AccountNumber == accountNumber 
            select o);

var holdingarray = rows.ToArray();
```

If that doesn't do the trick, you can just create your array, then loop through the rows, filling in the data.